# Why doesn't my Python script recognize a class from an imported module?

Tags: python, module

**collection.py**

```
import sys
import os
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

class Collection():
    """returns a collection curser from mongodb"""

    client = MongoClient()

    def __init__(self, db, collection_name):
        self.db = db
        self.collection_name = collection_name

    def getCollection(self):
        data_base = getattr(self.client, self.db)
        collObject = getattr(data_base, self.collection_name)
        return collObject
```

**main.py**

```
import sys
import os
import collection

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print"Begin Main"

    agents = Collection('hkpr_restore','agents')
    print "agents is" , agents
```

These files are in the same directory. When I run `main.py`, however, I get an error:

```
Begin Main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    agents = Collection('hkpr_restore','agents')
NameError: name 'Collection' is not defined
```

From what I've read, if the files are in the same directory, all I need to do is use `import collection`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: look how MongoClient is imported into collection.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've only imported `collection`, not `Collection`.

Either do `from collection import Collection`, or use the full qualified name when instantiating: `agents = collection.Collection('hkpr_restore','agents')`.